# Swift 4 Audio share with Whatsapp

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp

I would like to share audio (.mp3) file via WhatsApp. I used UIActivityViewController but it just share mp3 files link not the file. How can i share the file to WhatsApp? 
There is my code:

```
 @IBAction func playTusu(_ sender: Any) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://freesound.org/data/previews/405/405511_2731495-lq.mp3")!
    let playerItem = CachingPlayerItem(url: url)

    playerItem.delegate = self

    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
    player.play()

}

@IBAction func paylas(_ sender: Any) {
    let url: [Any] = ["https://freesound.org/data/previews/405/405511_2731495-lq.mp3"]
    let avc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: url, applicationActivities: nil)
    self.present(avc, animated: true)
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to first download your mp3 data, save it locally in your app and use UIDocumentInteractionController to share it to WhatsApp

Comment: Hmm, how can i download mp3 data?

Comment: Complete example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46457518/2303865

Answer (score 2):

In your `paylas` function you are trying to share a `String` but it should actually be a `URL`. The question has also been answered here: [How do I share an Audio File in an App using Swift 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263742/how-do-i-share-an-audio-file-in-an-app-using-swift-3)

```
@IBAction func paylas(_ sender: Any) {
    let url: [Any] = [audioFileURL]
    let avc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: url, applicationActivities: nil)
    self.present(avc, animated: true)
}
```

**Update**

The question says that you have a file but you only have the URL to the audio.

As @Leo Dabus mentioned in the comments, you have to download the audio and create a file first. Have a look at this SO question [Download mp3 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290458/xcode-download-mp3-file). You also have to wait until the audio has downloaded. Then, you can share the file. Make sure to do that on the UI / Main Thread.

Comment: I tried but same problem. It sends just link again.

Comment: You should at least mention where this info added into your answer came from

Comment: I did not see your comment until now. I did not mean to use your comment for my answer, sorry. :) Should I mention you or will you create your own answer?

Comment: @Yannick thats not true I already deleted my comment with that link

Comment: Btw you need to tell OP that after downloading the data asynchronously he needs to share it from the main thread

Comment: I saw it before you deleted it but after I changed my answer. I'm not here to take credit for someone else's work. I'll update the answer